# Change default properties for .resx files created with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resources, default-value

When creating a new .resx file anywhere in my solution, I would like the following properties to be other than the default:

- Copy to Output Directory: `Copy if newer`
- Custom Tool namespace: `Booking.Resources`
- Access Modifier: `public`

Is there any way I can change the default Visual Studio behavior on creation of these files, so I don't have to make the above changes manually each time?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to one-third of your question is here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/f77d5599-8f7e-4067-86f5-053f3c468a7b

You'll need to adjust the version number in the registry path... VS 2010 is version 10, VS 2008 is 9, etc...

Hope this helps...

~ Cameron